# regex to match special character 

Tags: regex, perl

There're many special characters in one text file(Line Terminator: LF; File encoding: utf-8) I'm processing, two of which are  and . Their corresponding hex codes are `\xf4\x80\x91\x9a` and `\xf4\x80\x91\x9d`.

For testing purpose, you can put the following text into a text file 1.txt: `a  and a  at the line end` or you can use this file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-8oZaLb86x0JE_gFpTkeX9jrbh3OXbF/view?usp=sharing

In editors like Sublime, I can't match these special characters using their hex codes.
Not sure if there're other ways to do that.

With perl, I cannot match them either. I want to delete all these hamburger-like characters using regex:

`perl -Mutf8::all -pE's,\xf4\x80\x91\x9a,,g; s,\xf4\x80\x91\x9d,,g;' 1.txt >  2.txt`

Is there some way I can do that?

Comment: Are these UTF-8 encoded characters? According to [this page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10045a/index.htm) "\xf4\x80\x91\x9a" is not a valid unicode character.

Comment: You have provided insufficient information -- what is an origin of the file? In Windows 10, `notepad++` -- mark symbol you try to replace, press `Ctrl+H` and enter substitution (empty in your case) press `Replace all` -- done. Repeat for second symbol same procedure. Note: perhaps these symbols are in UTF-16x or UTF-32 encoding -- without knowing the origin of the file impossible to say for sure.

Comment: You can try as a `dirty trick` to utilize `s/(|)//g;` but you still need to read file properly and indicate what it's encoding.

Comment: This `perl -wE'$hc = "\xf4\x80\x91\x9a"; $s = "hi".$hc; say $s; $s =~ s{$hc}{}g; say $s'` works for me. Am I missing something...?

Comment: @Polar Bear Indeed I can copy the symbols and replace. The symbols look the same, but are not actually the same under the hood. So I wonder if there's some way to replace them all using regex once and for all.

Comment: @zdim  If the special character is in the form of a variable, that should work. They're in a text file. I can't make it work.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland Yes, the file's encoding is UTF-8. It seems an invalid character; It can't be displayed normally in an editor like other characters. They appear in hamburger-like shape in some editors, or a question mark in others.

Comment: @jonah_w Can you upload the file somewhere? If you provide a download link we can try to investigate further

Comment: @Håkon Hægland https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-8oZaLb86x0JE_gFpTkeX9jrbh3OXbF/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to read the file as bytes/binary (using `:raw` IO layer):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'test.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<:raw', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $txt = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
my @replace = ("\xf4\x80\x91\x9a", "\xf4\x80\x91\x9d");
my ($pat ) = map {qr/$_/} join "|", map quotemeta, @replace;
$txt =~ s/$pat//g;
print $txt;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly for the two special characters. Is it possible to cover more situations than just two special characters? I just tried modifying the code and changing the `$pat` part to `my ($pat ) = qr/quotemeta('\xf4\x80\x91[\x9a-\x9d]')/;` . But it seems not to work.

Comment: You should not use `quotemeta` on a regex that should be interpreted like a regex (not as a  literal string). Instead you can use a normal regex like `my $pat = qr/\xf4\x80\x91[\x9a-\x9d]/`